# Python: Truncating a string and combining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

## What I want to achieve

My code below scrapes a website and exports the data frame to excel file. However, I need to remove unnecessary characters from first column and combine them so that I do not need to rename months in excel file. Every row has a designation from website, HOZ18( December 2018 )' HOZ19 ( December 2019 ) which I am not interested in addition to "\". So, I just want December 18, January 19, February 20 etc in the first column.

## Code

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = "https://shared.websol.barchart.com/quotes/quote.php?page=quote&sym=ho&x=13&y=8&domain=if&display_ice=1&enabled_ice_exchanges=&tz=0&ed=0"

    res = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

    Contracts=[]
    LastPrice=[]


    data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2:]

    for td in data_rows:
       Contract = td.findAll('td')[0].text
       Contracts.append(Contract)
       LstPrice = td.findAll('td')[7].text
       LastPrice.append(LstPrice)

   df = pd.DataFrame({'Contracts': Contracts, 'Previous Settled': LastPrice})
```

## Output ( Only partial )

```
  0     Cash (HOY00)    2.1884
  1     Dec \'18 (HOZ18)    2.2371
  2     Jan \'19 (HOF19)    2.2238
  3     Feb \'19 (HOG19)    2.2125
```

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for Python code to change a string like `Dec \'18 (HOZ18)` into `December 2018`?

Comment: @DustinMichels _ Yes. This applies for all the months HOF19, HOG 19 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option that doesn't require `.apply()`. It assumes we are dealing with years in the 21st century, not sure if that will work for you. And it also stores the month as a number, which could be useful, if not you can remove that bit.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime

# Data setup.

data = pd.DataFrame(['Dec \'18 (HOZ18)', 'Jan \'19 (HOF19)', 'Feb \'19 (HOG19)'], columns = ['string'])

# Extract the month number using regex, then map it to a month number.

data['month_number'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(re.sub('\s\'.*', '', i), '%b').month for i in data['string']]

# Extract the year, prepend '20' and store as an integer.

data['year'] = [int('20' + re.search('\d\d', i).group(0)) for i in data['string']]

print(data)
```

Giving:

```
            string  month_number  year
0  Dec '18 (HOZ18)            12  2018
1  Jan '19 (HOF19)             1  2019
2  Feb '19 (HOG19)             2  2019
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert a string like `Dec \'18 (HOZ18)` into `December 18`, here is one solution.

**1) Define a function to clean the strings:**

```
# define a dictionary to convert short month names to full ones
month_mapper = {
    'Jan': 'January',
    'Feb': 'February',
    'Mar': 'March',
    'Apr': 'April',
    'May': 'May',
    'Jun': 'June',
    'Jul': 'July',
    'Aug': 'August',
    'Sep': 'September',
    'Oct': 'October',
    'Nov': 'November',
    'Dec': 'December',
}

def clean_month_string(s):
    # replace the '\' char with empty string
    s = s.replace('\\', '')

    # split into three pieces on space
    # eg, "Dec '18 (HOZ18)" ->
    #   month = "Dec"
    #   year = "'18"
    #   code = "(HOZ18)"
    month, year, code = s.split(' ')

    # convert month using month mapper
    month = month_mapper[month]

    # remove the ' at the start of the year
    year = year.replace("'", "")

    # return new month and new year (dropping code)
    return ' '.join([month, year])
```

**2) Apply that function to each row in your DataFrame using `apply`.**

```
# drop that first row, which is not properly formatted
df = df.drop(0).reset_index(drop=True)

# apply the function to your 'Contracts' series.
df['Contracts'] = df['Contracts'].apply(clean_month_string)
```

Comment: Thanks. Or may I was thinking just add Months to data frame based on index. Can that be done? Because row1 is current month and so on.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. It would roughly involve taking the index `mod` 12, and then looking up that number in a list of 12 months.

Comment: @I am getting error below                                                                                  df['Contracts'] = df['Contracts'].apply(clean_month_string)                                         TypeError: clean_month_string() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Also, which code gets to know that row0 should be current month and so on going forward for remaining rows?

Comment: I can run it without errors. Try removing the parenthesis from the apply statement: `.apply(clean_month_string())` --> `.apply(clean_month_string)`. Apply applies the function to every row in the series essentially at once, rather than requiring you to iterate over each row one at a time!

Comment: Can you please provide a syntax for a function you are calling? I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Appreciate your time and efforts for this.